# Why does my variable reset to 0 in my Unity C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple project with a button in a scene that, when tapped, starts the StartWorking function in this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class DoWork : MonoBehaviour {

  public int Cash = 5;

  public void StartWorking() {
        Debug.Log (Cash);
        Debug.Log ("Ran!");
        Cash++;
        Debug.Log (Cash);
  }
}
```

When ran and on tapping the button the console says:

0
  Ran!
  1

instead of expected:

5
  Ran!
  6

Any idea why the variable is not keeping it's set initial value in the class?

Thanks.

Comment: since the property is public I supose somewhere `Cash` is set to 0 before you call `StartWorking`

Comment: Your code won't _even_ compile I think.

Comment: Maybe the Unity engine is creating a new instance on each call? try to make the int static.

Comment: Static is not meant to be used to fix issue. It has a proper purpose and that is not it right there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a variable is public, the value on the script does not matter. You probably have it as 0 in Inspector and this is the value used at runtime. If you want the value of the script to be used, you need to click the component setting wheel and Reset component.

If you have to see the value but want to use the script value, make it private and click the little down arrow next to the lock on top of the inspector. This will display private member as well. You won't be able to change them though via inspector, just look.

Comment: Hi, I see the now in the inspector the Cash has a value of 0 and when I change it it updates when I run the program.  However how do I set it to use the script value instead?  When I do "Reset" for that script the value in the inspector for Cash doesn't change.  Thanks!

Comment: If you press Reset, the top button on the component settings, it has to change. It does for me.

Answer (score 3):

`Cash` variable is public and I think you change the value of `Cash` in `inspector`.

Once you change the value of a variable in inspector, unity will ignore the initial value in code and replace it with value in inspector.

Try to change `public int Cash = 5;` to `private int Cash = 5;` and you will get the result you want

Answer (score 1):

Is your script linked to an object in the scene ? If it's the case, the "cash" variable can be edited in the inspector and overwrite the initialisation in your script.